# PasswordStrength Positioning issue

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How do we position the AjaxControl PasswordStrength relative to the TextBox in which the password is entered ? Based on the ValidationSummary displayed, the textbox gets moved down, while the PasswordStrength remains floated/absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DisplayPosition="RightSide"` on the `ajaxToolkit:PasswordStrength` object.
If that doesn't work, that's due to restraints e.g.: columnwidth on a table.

If the summary and the strength overlap, put the summary in a different tablerow, div, use br, whatever.

Regards,

M.